# How do I send validation code to Mobile

Tags: algorithm, validation, mobile, sms

I would like to know the process and service providers who will enable me to send the validation text to users mobile in order to verify the user.

I have seen validation text from facebook that it sends to its users whenever validation is needed.

I would like to build similar system

Comment: Which language you like to use for that

Comment: I am comfortable with php, .net, java but prefer php for web based solutions and .net for desktop based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example specifically for phone verification [using PHP and Twilio](http://blog.twilio.com/2010/05/sms-phone-verification-with-twilio-and-php.html) (where I work)

Comment: thnx it was gr8 helpful... well now i am wondering about sms gateway or some account like twilo with low rate

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to find a suitable SMS gateway provider.

Now if you were able to find one that suits you (price, network coverage, etc), they usually provide various examples how to use their messaging APIs and sometimes even provide helpful code snippets and tutorials on their own website.

There are also bunch of high-level open source projects available in different languages and providers, but as there's no language currently specified, I'm not going to list these here...

Comment: Ah.. forgot, there's also possibility to hook up your own phone and send SMS from there (although, this is only suitable for low volume of messages).